# Configuring Correct Permissions in Firebase Cloud Function to Avoid CORS Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a complex web application built with React JS, utilizing Firebase services such as Auth and Firestore. Currently, I am facing an issue regarding setting the correct permissions for my cloud function.

I have a cloud function named task-DoTask hosted in the Europe-west3 region, which is configured to be callable from the client side using Firebase's onCall method.

To manage this function, I access its settings through the google cloud console

In each of my functions, I am also using Firebase Auth to check the `context.auth` object to secure the function further. Here is a snippet of how one of my functions looks:

```
export const DoTask = functions
  .region("europe-west3")
  .runWith({
    enforceAppCheck: true,
    consumeAppCheckToken: true,
    timeoutSeconds: 240,
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Check the authentication of the user
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "unauthenticated", 
        "The function must be called while authenticated."
      );
    }
    
    // ... (rest of your function)
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // ... (resolve or reject based on your business logic)
    });
  });
```

Under the "Permissions" tab of this function in the Google Cloud Console, I currently have the "allUsers" permission enabled, allowing Google Cloud callers to invoke this function. However, when I remove this option, all of my users encounter a CORS error when trying to call the function.

[allUsers permission image from cloud functions console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tFYW.png)

I attempted to remove the "allUsers" permission and tried setting up other permissions, but without success. I was expecting to find a more secure alternative to the "allUsers" permission that would prevent the CORS error from occurring. Currently, I am still using the "allUsers" permission as I have not found a safer solution yet.

I am concerned that attackers might abuse this setting by making numerous requests to my function, which could potentially increase the billing of my project significantly.

My queries are as follows:
For security reasons, is it advisable to retain the "allUsers" permission, or should it be removed?
If it is recommended to remove the "allUsers" permission, what should be the alternative permission setting to avoid CORS errors while ensuring security?
Thank you for your insights. Looking forward to hearing your expert advice.

Comment: allUsers doesn't have anything to do with CORS.  Firebase Authentication also has nothing to do with CORS.  Callable type functions should automatically handle CORS internally and there is nothing you can do to change that.  It should just work as long as you're also using the Firebase client library to invoke the callable.  But you haven't said anything about how you invoke the functions, so it's impossible to say what you might be doing wrong.  Please edit the question to show your client code so we can see what you're doing and what yields the error.

Comment: If you remove the allUsers permission, then your client app will no longer be able to invoke the function.  So that's a requirement you can't change.

Comment: thanks you @DougStevenson 
but if i keep it like that (with the allUsers permission) a toast message say that keeping allUsers is not recommended because all who have access to the internet can call it

Comment: But that's exactly what you need in order for the function to work the way your app requires.  You can ignore the message.  Your code to check for authentication restricts it from being used by anyone who isn't authenticated.

Comment: ok @DougStevenson but this prevents the content of the function from executing
but that does not prevent the execution of the functions so it could still be called hundreds of times (DDoS) and caused problems on the server
do you understand my point of reflection ?

Comment: That's how it works - you pay for usage. This has been discussed in detail i many forums.  If you think your project is subject to abuse, contact Firebase support with the details.